# Sql Membership for ASP.NET, Learning Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, sqlmembershipprovider

I am quite a beginner to ASP.NET. Recently, I started to learn ASP.NET WebForm. I created a web application where I needed to implement the login and registration form.

Could you tell me about the best resources (book, video, tutorial, etc...) to learn/start the SQL Membership with ASP.NET WebForm from the scratch?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for Web Forms, you need to use the new Identity membership system. Here are some resources, the first link is the general list of Identity resources, the second is a more specific example of how to apply Identity to an existing Web Forms project.

[ASP.NET Identity Resources](http://www.asp.net/identity)

[Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project)